# Get image from web and display using Synapse

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus, ararat-synapse

I want to get an image from the web into stream (without saving) and displaying it on TImage.
The following code produces an error:

```
response := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
   HttpGetBinary('http://www.example-url/example_image.jpg', response);
   Image.Picture.LoadFromStream(response);
finally
   response.Free;
end;
```

Project ------- raised exception class 'EReadError' with message:
Stream read error

This is the function in Synapse library(in the picture.inc) that the error points to:

```
function TPicFileFormatsList.FindByStreamFormat(Stream: TStream): TGraphicClass;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Count - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    Result := GetFormats(I)^.GraphicClass;
    if Result.IsStreamFormatSupported(Stream) then   // <<<<<< this is the error line
      Exit;
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;
```

Comment: Set the stream position to the beginning before you load it to the image. Like `response.Position := 0; Image.Picture.LoadFromStream...`

Comment: I tried that before posting here. The result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the `JPEGLib` unit somewhere in your project, so that the JPEG graphic class gets registered.

```
uses
  JPEGLib, // to support JPEG
  PNGcomn, // to support PNG
  httpsend;

response := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
   if HttpGetBinary('http://www.example-url/example_image.jpg', response) then
   begin
     response.Seek( 0, soFromBeginning );
     Image.Picture.LoadFromStream( response );
   end;
finally
   response.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I don't have FPC by hand but I think that if the `TImage.Picture` has the `LoadFromStream` method, there should be a chance to load it directly from stream. It's the `TPicFileFormatsList.FindByStreamFormat` method that fails, so couldn't the problem be (except resetting the stream position) in missing unit which registers the JPEG format ? It's just a wild guess...

Comment: +1 @TLama You are totally right ... FPC differs in that point from Delphi :o)

Comment: This works. The JPEGLib and PNGcomn are not necessary, the debugger gives the message that they are not being used in my unit. I should have mentioned that I use FPC and not Delphi :). Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so the only problem was that you didn't reset the stream position ? You've told me that you tried that and you got the same result...

Comment: This: response.Position := 0 did not work. This: response.Seek(0, soFromBeginning) worked. Dunno... I admit I am not really familiar with stream.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. They even warn that the [`TStream.Position`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstream.position.html) is not supported by all descendants. And `TMemoryStream` is one of those. From `TMemoryStream` you can [`only read`](https://github.com/graemeg/freepascal/blob/master/rtl/objpas/classes/classesh.inc#L941) the stream position, not set. Weird design...

Comment: @TLama The setter `SetPosition` is definied in `TStream` and calls `Seek( Pos, soFromBeginning );` by default. So this should work ... and just verified by a test `respond.Position := 0;` does the job as well